# How can I use floor function with a decision variable in CPLEX? TypeError: must be real number, not LinearExpr

Tags: python, cplex, constraint-programming, floor

I am solving an optimization problem with docplex in python. I want to use the math.floor function to round down the value of a decision variable x1[a] to the nearest number with 1/6 steps.

I have defined a function named discrete_time(x,a). I use this function to discretize x1[a] which is a decision variable.

But I receive "TypeError: must be real number, not LinearExpr."

Does ayone know how can I solve this error and how can I use floor function on a decision variable?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
def discret_time(x,a): #x = time in hours, a = length of dicretization steps in hours for example a = 1/6 means discretization in 1/6 hour intervals
    return math.floor(x/a)*a

labels = ['home', 'study', 'work']

x1 = m.continuous_var_dict(labels, lb = 0, name = 'x1') #start time

for a in labels:
    discret_start_a1 = discret_time(x1[a], 1/6)
```

Comment: Is this inside your model, or when extracting the solution? If it is part of your model passed to CPLEX then you should use Alex's approach or similar. If it is during the extraction of the solution after solving, then you should get the value of the CPLEX expression or variable which should be a standard python double or similar and then you can use your standard python functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `discrete_time()` to:

```
def discrete_time(x,a):
  return int(x/a)*a
```

[OR]

```
def discrete_time(x,a):
  temp = 0
  while(temp<=x):
    temp+=a
  temp-=a
  return temp
```

math.floor() expects only integer type.

Answer (score 0):

You should linéarize floor

See [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithdocplex/blob/main/floor.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='floor')

r=range(0,4)
x=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999]

y = mdl.integer_var_list(4,0,1000,name="y")
f = mdl.continuous_var_list(4,0,0.99999,name="f")

for i in r:
    mdl.add(x[i]==y[i]+f[i])

mdl.solve()

for i in r:
    print(x[i]," ==> ",y[i].solution_value) from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='floor')

r=range(0,4)
x=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999]

y = mdl.integer_var_list(4,0,1000,name="y")
f = mdl.continuous_var_list(4,0,0.99999,name="f")

for i in r:
    mdl.add(x[i]==y[i]+f[i])

mdl.solve()

for i in r:
    print(x[i]," ==> ",y[i].solution_value)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have linearized the function and now it is working.